# How to toggle WIFI or GPRS network using java code on android platform?

Tags: android

I'm tring to add a feature that users can toggle WIFI and GPRS network by clicking a button. But i can't find a official api to do this.Could you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
  android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And implement the Receiver with something like this:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = 
connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = 
connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
  //Do something
if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
  //Do something else
}}}
```

Have you found this while searching?